# How can I determine why OpenGL entry points are missing after updating my graphics driver

Tags: c++, opengl

I recently updated my graphics drivers and I now find that many procedures are not found in the opengl library. I'm using gl3w which generates the following code for loading and binding to the OpenGl entry points. Note that this code was working perfectly fine before updating my drivers. I have added some strings to generate debug messages but otherwise the code is as created by gl3w:

```
static void open_libgl(void)
{
    libgl = LoadLibraryA("opengl32.dll");
}

static void close_libgl(void)
{
    FreeLibrary(libgl);
}

static GL3WglProc get_proc(const char *proc)
{
    GL3WglProc res;
    std::string debugMessage = "WGL Load procedure : ";
    res = (GL3WglProc) wglGetProcAddress(proc);
    if (!res)
    {
        debugMessage = "    Load procedure : ";
        res = (GL3WglProc) GetProcAddress(libgl, proc);    // any attempt to get procedures from here fail (res == null)
    }
    debugMessage.append(proc);
    if(!res)
    {
        debugMessage.append("  FAILED !!!");
    }
    DEBUG_PRINT(debugMessage.c_str());
    return res;
}

int gl3wInit(void)
{
    open_libgl();
    load_procs();
    close_libgl();
    return parse_version();
}
```

The ouput debug messages from above are a long list of the OpenGL procedures that were found or missing (FAILED !!!):

(partial list):

```
 WGL Load procedure : glVertexAttribP3uiv
 WGL Load procedure : glVertexAttribP4ui
 WGL Load procedure : glVertexAttribP4uiv
     Load procedure : glDrawArraysIndirect  FAILED !!!
     Load procedure : glDrawElementsIndirect  FAILED !!!
     Load procedure : glUniform1d  FAILED !!!
     Load procedure : glUniform2d  FAILED !!!
     Load procedure : glUniform3d  FAILED !!!
     Load procedure : glUniform4d  FAILED !!!
     Load procedure : glUniform1dv  FAILED !!!
```

The code produced by gl3w is designed to first check for an entry point using wglGetProcAddress and if not found it will try GetProcAddress. Examining the output I find that any attempt to find the procedures using GetProcAddress are returning null (not found).

Any advice on how to debug this would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

System Details:
Windows 7
Microsoft VS 2012
MSI laptop core-i7 with Intel HD 4000
NVIDIA GeForce GTX680M graphics driver version: 353.62

Comment: Problems like that are sometimes due to the fact that your program is using the Intel HD instead of the nvidia. Sometimes updates reset the option that say "always use nvidia".

Comment: @Jerem Big Thanks! - That's exactly what happened. I do have validation checks in place for the OpenGL version, but my validation version was set lower than what I actually need. The Intel HD driver was OpenGL 3 - very old, even though the computer is only 2 years old.

Comment: If you want to avoid the problem in the future, check this: http://developer.download.nvidia.com/devzone/devcenter/gamegraphics/files/OptimusRenderingPolicies.pdf there's a variable to declare in your code to force the nvidia card to be used.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
res = (GL3WglProc) wglGetProcAddress(proc);
if (!res)
{
    debugMessage = "    Load procedure : ";
    res = (GL3WglProc) GetProcAddress(libgl, proc);    // any attempt to get procedures from here fail (res == null)
}
```

is not quite correct. According to [opengl.org](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Load_OpenGL_Functions#Windows):

> While the MSDN documentation says that `wglGetProcAddress`​ returns `NULL` on failure, some implementations will return other values. `1`, `2`, and `3` are used, as well as `-1`.

So you may be missing some functions, by simply not testing all possible results. Linked article also provides sample function for loading GL functions:

```
void *GetAnyGLFuncAddress(const char *name)
{
  void *p = (void *)wglGetProcAddress(name);
  if(p == 0 ||
    (p == (void*)0x1) || (p == (void*)0x2) || (p == (void*)0x3) ||
    (p == (void*)-1) )
  {
    HMODULE module = LoadLibraryA("opengl32.dll");
    p = (void *)GetProcAddress(module, name);
  }

  return p;
}
```

Try if this works. Also, remember, that in order to load GL entry points, you need to have a valid context bound - you have, don't you?

By the way, are you sure you want to do this manually? [GLEW](http://glew.sourceforge.net/) is probably the best and the most portable way of doing it.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. I am using GL3W , which is a similar extension wrangler [link](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_Loading_Library#GL3W) . The code snippet here is from their .cpp class which I only added some ability for debug messages to reveal what's going on there.

Comment: Instead of testing for 1, 2, 3, it suffices to see if the lowermost 2 bits are set. Function pointers are always aligned to at least 4 bytes (32 bits architecture) or 8 bytes (64 bits architecture), so any returned value p where `((uintptr_t)p & 3)` is not a valid pointer, i.e. `if(!p || (((uintptr_t)p) & 3)) { ... }`

Comment: Are there any citations for these values?

Comment: No, I don't think so. As I said, MSDN mentions only `NULL` as a failure indicator. However, I have encountered `0x01` and `0x03` myself. Other two values were also reported on some forums (even here, on SO, IIRC).

Comment: _> However, I have encountered `0x01` and `0x03` myself._ - Do you happen to remember examples of cases and implementations in which such things occur?